# Issue uploading file via AJAX in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Aware there are a few questions around this topic, I have been searching through them most of this evening trying to find a solution to my problem. This is the first time I have worked on such task.

I am trying to upload a file via AJAX in WordPress. I have set up AJAX in WordPress and the connection works fine, until I try to pass the form data at which stage I am getting a 'bad request' error and no other information other than this.

The AJAX callback function in WordPress is simple enough:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_calendar_process', 'calendar_process' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_calendar_process', 'calendar_process' );

function calendar_process() {
    echo "worked";
    die();
}
```

My front end form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" class="custom-cal-form">
        <input type="file" accept=".ics" name="custom-calendar" id="custom_cal_file" />

        <button class="submit-ajax">Update Calendars</button>
    </form>
```

And my AJAX call looks like this:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.submit-ajax', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var file_data = jQuery('#custom_cal_file').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        console.log(form_data);

        jQuery.ajax({

            url : calendarprocess.ajax_url,
            type : 'post',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data : {
                action : 'calendar_process',
                post_id : 'test',
                calendar : form_data
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                jQuery('.ajax-response').html( response );
            }
        });

    });
```

I was originally getting the error

> Can only call FormData.append on instances of FormData

Until I looked around at some questions and added

> processData: false,
>               contentType: false,

To my form and now the full error I get is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request)

Which of course signals that WordPress is not happy.

Really hoping someone can add some insight into this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with WordPress, but sounds like your URL is bad. If you're trying to concatenate those two "variables?" together, "." is not valid in Javascript. You're looking for "+". Not seeing where those are being initiated at, so if that's something WP specific, ignore that, lol.

First thing I'd do to debug is hard code the address to the page you're calling first. I.E.  "test/test.php". That would at least tell you if it's a valid address.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't really apply to WordPress as WordPress handles the AJAX calls, the AJAX url is being localised in the functions.php. The code works perfectly until I try to pass the form data so the issue would seem to be with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form so please try to add it.

```
<form method="post" class="custom-cal-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added that - still the same issue though unfortunately...